# Javascript - User script - how do I extract links on twitter that links to another tweet?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I stumbled across this: https://twitter.com/doctorow/status/1586238115223568384 (this is the linker)

What's interesting is that this tweet, that links to this tweet: https://twitter.com/doctorow/status/1585913960741609472 (linked tweet) when clicking on it. HOWEVER, this is strange, it does not use `a href` nor tags that function similarly. Not only that, when you hover your mouse over it, your browser is supposed to display the destination URL on the bottom-left corner but did not so. What surprises me the most is that on the linker tweet, I inspect element the page's HTML and tried to find the string `1585913960741609472` which is the tweet ID of the tweet of the destination link, surprised that the search did not find any. So, how do I extract a linked tweet while being on the linker page? Is this behavior purly on twitter's javascript that a userscript cannot access? Here is the picture of an element somehow has a link.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The page is a [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) where those "links" are not present in the source HTML or initial JavaScript, but are communicated to the client through an API request. There's a click event listener on a section of the page that, when clicked, changes around the DOM, makes some API requests, and changes the current URL to something new *without being an `<a>`*.

You could implement something similar yourself with:

```
fetch(someApi)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((url) => {
    document.querySelector('section').addEventListener('click', () => {
      window.history.pushState({}, '', url)
    });
  });
```

For Twitter in particular, it looks like the tweet ID is first gotten from Twitter's internal API, whose URL starts with

```
https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/lwMlLKa0uCr-By_siQJaGQ/TweetDetail?variables=%7B%22focalTweetId..........
```

which contains a large JSON, which has, among other things

```
"quoted_status_result":{"result":{"__typename":"Tweet","rest_id":"1585913960741609472","core":{"user_results":{"result":{"__typename":"User","id":"VXNlcjo
```

To access this with a userscript, you would have to hook onto the XHR made by the page. One way would be to overwrite `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` with your own function - if the method is called with a pattern-matching URL (perhaps `https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/`), add a `readystatechange` listener to the XHR so that you can parse the response body when it comes back (while continuing to allow Twitter to parse the response too).